# ElementTree wrong encoding

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, elementtree

im searching like for hours but I cant find the solution online so im trying to ask you now here in this topic.

I just want to print the inside Content of a html tag in a xml document but im getting only things like (&lt, &gt, and and and...)

It looks like this in the XML Document

```
        <data table="tt_content" elementUid="2490" key="tt_content:NEW/1/2490:bodytext"><![CDATA[<img src="/fileadmin/public/Redaktion/Bilder/Icons/Icon-CE.png" width="28" height="21" class="float-left mt-1 mr-2">
<h4>EU-Baumusterprüfbescheinigung</h4>
```

When I print it it looks like this

```
<data table="tt_content" elementUid="2490" key="tt_content:NEW/1/2490:bodytext">&lt;img src="/fileadmin/public/Redaktion/Bilder/Icons/Icon-CE.png" width="28" height="21" class="float-left mt-1 mr-2"&gt;
&lt;h4&gt;EU-Baumusterpr&#252;fbescheinigung&lt;/h4&gt;
```

as you can see it is very different not only the german characters not being displayed but also the "CDATA" which is very important to me.
There are replaced with &lt.. and so on.

And now to my Code

```
raw = <data table="tt_content" elementUid="2490" key="tt_content:NEW/1/2490:bodytext"><![CDATA[<img src="/fileadmin/public/Redaktion/Bilder/Icons/Icon-CE.png" width="28" height="21" class="float-left mt-1 mr-2">
<h4>EU-Baumusterprüfbescheinigung</h4>


raw = ET.tostring(data).decode()
print(raw) # print is showed before



What I've also tried
# raw = ET.tostring(raw, encoding='unicode', method='xml')
# raw = ET.tostring(raw, encoding='unicode', method='xml')
```

At first im iterating to the position where i have the data table which i showed you before

```
def copy_content():
    for pageGrp in root.findall('pageGrp'):
        for data in pageGrp.iter('data'):
            tag = data.get("key").split(":")[2]
            if (tag == "bodytext"):
                raw = ET.tostring(data).decode()     IT Starts HERE
                # ET.dump(data)
                # print(raw)
                # file = open('new.xml', 'a')
                # file.write(raw)
                print(raw)
```

I hope you can help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is unclear how to reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The code is incomplete. Where does the `data` variable come from?

Comment: this is the reason why before i had the full code so that you can see what im doing, i updated it againg @mzjn i hope you can help me

Comment: ElementTree does not preserve CDATA sections. If you parse an XML document and later save it or use `tostring()`, the CDATA markup is gone.